# Meaning of "By the time"

Tags: meaning

> Graduating with a bachelor's or master's degree from a college or university located in a country where the primary language is English by the time you would start the Ph.D. Program would qualify for a TOEFL waiver.

As shown above, does it mean:

1. You have to come to the Ph.D. program right after your graduation, then you are exempt from the TOEFL requirement.

or

2. As long as you have graduated, either 1 week ago or ten years ago, you are still eligible for the TOEFL waiver.

Please clarify my confusion.

Comment: It'd probably be better to ask an expert on this particular topic, as it's not immediately clear from the way the sentence is phrased.

Comment: It means that whoever wrote that sentence flunked English composition.

Answer (score 0):

> Graduating with a bachelor's or master's degree from a college or university located in a country where the primary language is English by the time you would start the Ph.D. Program would qualify for a TOEFL waiver.

As others have pointed out, this is poorly written. It could be improved by getting rid of the first 'would'. Here's an improved version. (I've also added parentheses although they are not strictly necessary.)

Graduating (with a bachelor's or master's degree from a college or university located in a country where the primary language is English) by the time you start the Ph.D. Program would qualify you for a TOEFL waiver.

I think they are trying to say that you do not have to have graduated at the time you *apply* for the PhD. However, in order to get the waiver, you must graduate at such a university before *starting* on the PhD.

Really however the whole sentence appears to be a product of verbal indigestion.

Comment: Are both answers necessary??

Answer (score 0):

> Graduating with a bachelor's or master's degree from a college or university located in a country where the primary language is English by the time you would start the Ph.D. Program would qualify for a TOEFL waiver.

As others have pointed out, this is poorly written. It could be improved by getting rid of the first 'would'. Here's an improved version. (I've also added parentheses although they are not strictly necessary.)

Graduating (with a bachelor's or master's degree from a college or university located in a country where the primary language is English) by the time you start the Ph.D. Program would qualify you for a TOEFL waiver.

I think they are trying to say that you do not have to have graduated at the time you *apply* for the PhD. However, in order to get the waiver, you must graduate at such a college before *starting* on the PhD.  They have made a simple concept complicated and maybe it means something completely different.

This is a case of verbal constipation.